# Will calling "walletpassphrase" twice in a short amount of time increase the time the wallet stays unlocked?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, api

The Bitcoin API call for walletpassphrase allows one to open the wallet for a set amount of time. If one calls it again while the wallet is still unlocked, we get an error of 'Error: Wallet is already unlocked.'. Does the call extend the amount of time the wallet is unlocked, or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some experiments it appears that as calling the function results in an error, it is not processed, and thus the unlock time is not extended.

Comment: Right.  And that's quite annoying functionality.  If I want to make a payment, I run the unlock command, then make the payment.  If it happens that the wallet was already unlocked, but was due to lock again 1 second later, the unlock call fails, and then the wallet has locked itself before I can make the payment.  I just reported a github issue about this: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/1528 because it has been annoying me for some time.

Comment: @ChrisMoore I also posted the issue earlier - https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/1527 .

Comment: Ugly workarounds: call walletlock before walletpassphrase.

Or call getinfo to see if the wallet is unlocked (and get the time of when it will be locked again)